# frustrating .load() situation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a frustrating situation here and I do not know how to solve it... Its not rocket science, so what am I missing?

Why would a `$(window).load(function(){//stuff here});` load event work fine and when I use a load event in this context`$('.simpleShow *').load(function(){//stuff here});` it does not work at all?

The `$('.simpleShow')` part is for an image preloader, which is simply an absolutely placed div class that is supposed to fade away once the image is loaded... Here is the code snippet:

```
$('.simpleShow').load(function()
{
    $('.mediaPreloader').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

The corresponding HTML block:

```
<div class="simpleShow-wrapper" id="show000">
    <div class="mediaPreloader">&nbsp;</div>
        <!-- images / -->
        <div class="simpleShow">
            All my images placed here here
        </div>
        <!-- / images -->
    </div>
```

I know Chrome has issues with some jQuery goodies, but I use XAMPP and have not had any trouble of any sort with jQuery scripts and besides, this is not the only script I use in the site... Chrome does not throw any error either.
Any help and or advice would be appreciated guys gals.

Regards,
Reinhardt

Comment: What are you trying to do? `load` expects a string as it's first parameter, as it's used to asynchronously load data from another page. If you're using jQuery > 1.8 then the way you're trying to use this function [has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: i think you meant to use `$('.simpleShow *').on("load",function(){//stuff here});`?

Comment: @BenFortune I'm trying to do a preloader for images/content. Once all the  goodies are loaded the preloader div is supposed to fade out. Isn't `.load()` supposed to execute a function once the elements in a specific div is done loading? im using v1.7

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan What is the difference between what I have done and your code suggestion? I did not notice any difference on my side...

Comment: jQuery.load() is for loading external resources, on() adds an event listener to the onLoad event

Answer (score 1):

A div doesn't fire a `load` event - it doesn't load anything. If you want the event to fire when an image is loaded then you need to attach the event to the `img` element. However the [documentation has caveats](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which you should read.

The jQuery `load()` event function has also been deprecated (as it is now used to load content via AJAX). You should use `.on( "load", handler )`.

Comment: I have changed it to `.on( "load", handler )`. It seems to be working on the index.thml page but none of the others... This is weird.